# Writing double summation in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, weighted-least-squares, vectorization

I have the following **weighted residuals sum of squares** (WRSS)

$$ \sum_{t=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n \left(y_i - \boldsymbol{x}_i^T \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}_t} \right)^2 (z_t - z_i) $$

where $y_i \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 1}$, $(z_t - z_i) \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times1}$, $\boldsymbol{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times1}$, $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_t \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times1}$. I want to put it in matrix form to increase my computation speed (i.e., avoid `for` loops). I did the following

$$ \sum_{t=1}^n \left(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol{X}  \boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_t \right)^T
\mbox{diag} \left( z_t - z_1, \ldots, z_t - z_n \right) \left(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol{X}  \boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_t \right) $$

I am not quite sure how to get rid of the summation over $t$. One suggestion

$$ \sum_{t=1}^n \left(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol{X}  \boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_t \right)^T
\left(\boldsymbol{I}_n z_t - \mbox{diag} (Z) \right) \left(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol{X}  \boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_t \right) $$

Then separate the terms with $t$. I work this out but I could not get anything useful.

$$ \sum_{t=1}^n \left[ \boldsymbol{y}^T\big(\boldsymbol{I}_n z_t - \mbox{diag}(Z)\big)\boldsymbol{y} +  \boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_t^T \boldsymbol{X}^T \big(\mbox{diag}(Z)-\boldsymbol{I}_n z_t\big) \boldsymbol{y} + \boldsymbol{y}^T \big(\mbox{diag}(Z)-\boldsymbol{I}_n z_t\big) \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_t + \boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_t^T \boldsymbol{X}^T \big(\boldsymbol{I}_n z_t - \mbox{diag}(Z)\big) \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_t\right] $$

The main goal for me is to avoid the `for` loops at all costs. Your help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\b{\beta}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Collect the indexed vectors into matrices
$$\eqalign{
B &= \m{\b_1&\b_2&\ldots&\b_n}\; &\in\bbR{p\times n} \\
X &= \m{x_1&x_2&\ldots&x_n}    &\in\bbR{p\times n} \\
}$$
Use these and the *all-ones* vector $\o\in\bbR{n\times\o}$
to create the matrices
$$\eqalign{
C &= y\o^T-X^TB   \;\;&\in\bbR{n\times n} \\
Q &= C\odot C &\in\bbR{n\times n} \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ is the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Finally, the **sum of squares** can be written as
$$\eqalign{
\LR{\o^TQz-z^TQ\o} \;=\; \o^T\big(Q-Q^T\big)z \\
}$$

Comment: It gives zero since $Q$ is a symmetric matrix. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MOHAMMED Note that $Q$ is not symmetric unless $C$ is symmetric. And $C$ isn't symmetric unless both $\;y={\tt1}\;$ **and** $\;X=B\;$ are true.  Since you didn't tell us anything about the vectors $\,\{x_k,\,\beta_k,\,y\}\;$ I suppose that it's _possible_ but it seems unlikely.